# Grab data from a specific struct by typing in name and year

Tags: c++, struct

I am building a wine inventory system for people who want to have an easy way of seeing the wine they own, which automatically gets its market price and county of creation.

this program should get a struct from multiple predefined structs seen in code below, by the user only typing name and year so it prints the entire struct, for example, I type in  "*Greenock creek Roennfelt road shiraz*" and the year "*2002*" then it outputs the entire struct seen below.
I was thinking of using a read or get command but before researching how I should do make this I wanted to ask if there was a more efficient way of doing this.

the struct below is just one of many in a large list of predetermined structs in a second c++ file connected to the main file.

is this possible in c++ if so how would you recommend proceeding?

A struct in a different file:

```
struct red1 // one of the predetermined structs 
{
    string name = "Greenock Creek Roennfeldt Road Shiraz";
    double year = 2002;
    string place = "Australia";
    double price = 295.00;
    string type = "Redwine";
};
```

Main File input: (this part is not 100% yet it's just to show what I mean.

```
for (int i = 3; i < 10; i++)
    {
        string str; //input for data
        cout << "Please enter the data of your Wine: " << endl;
        cout << "Enter name: ";
        getline(cin, wine.name);
        cout << endl << "Enter year: ";
        getline(cin, wine.year);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "your entered data: " << endl;
        printwine(wine);

        wineinventory.push_back(wine);  // store in vector
    }
```

Comment: the way you talk about structs suggests that you confuse the struct with instances of the struct. What you called `red1` should probably be just `wine` and then you probably want different instances of that struct for different wines. Once you got that straight you can put them in a vector, search the vector to find a `wine` with given name, and print its members (by using your `operator<<` overload)

Comment: Decide on a data file format, convert your struct definitions to that, and write code to read/modify/delete records from that file format. If you woud like to avoid reinventing the wheel, look at SQLite or even a simple JSON file.

Comment: "people who want to have an easy way of seeing the wine they own" first world problem or what? :P

Comment: @PaulEvans arent most coding "problems" really just first world problems?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I suppose, but something about "Blast it all! I'm going to have summon Jeeves to find out how much Domaine de la Romanee-Conti Grand Cru 1990 we have left in the cellar! If only there was a simpler way..." cracks me up! :)

Comment: You should use a database, something like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp .

Comment: `double year`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont understand why you want to have several structs. I think you need just one and then create different instances for different wines. For the sake of the example I will use only year and name:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct wine {
    int year;
    std::string name;
};

// custom output operator to insert a wine into a ostream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const wine& w) {
    out << "year: " << w.year << " " << w.name;
    return out;
};

int main() {

    // fill a vector with different wines
    std::vector<wine> wines { {2001,"the red one"}, {2005,"the white one"}};

    // select a year
    int year = 2001;

    // pick the ones with matching year and print them
    for (auto& w : wines) {
        if (w.year == year) std::cout << w << "\n";
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
year: 2001 the red one
```

Comment: Depending on number of wines in question, a `std::unordered_map` (or multimap) might be an interesting alternative.

Comment: @Aconcagua I just passed a serious "hammer it all with map" period and now that I am over it I am more in a "think twice if a map really does better than vector" mood ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua exactly, most appropriate for the specific problem, so use `std::vector` always. Just joking :P

Answer (score 1):

There is already an accepted answer with many upvotes. Very good.

I just wanted to guide the new user in the correct direction. Since we are working with C++, we should use a more object oriented approach.

You have data and you have methods that should work on your data. For example, your Wine object has properties, the data members. And only the Wine object should operate on thes members. So I added / overloaded an inserter and extractor function. The inserter knows, how to print its data. Later, you would even encapsulate your data, and nobody but the functions should operate on it. If you later add one property to the Wine, you will adapt the inserter and the rest of the program will continue to work. You need to make this abstraction.

So, I recomend to learn the object oriented approach, otherwise, you will continue to wriet C code with some syntactic C++ sugar.

I drafted a skeleton example program for you. It should give you an idea of what I mean

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// A wine with its data and methods
struct Wine
{
    std::string  name{};
    int          year{};
    std::string  place{};
    double       price{};
    std::string  type{};

    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Wine& w) {
        return is >> w.name >> w.year >> w.place >> w.price >> w.type;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Wine& w) {
        return os << w.name << "\n" << w.year << "\n" << w.place << "\n" << w.price << "\n" << w.type << "\n";
    }
};

// A Wine list (internally a vector) with its data and methods
class Wines
{
    std::vector<Wine> wines{};
public:
    void add(Wine& wine) { wines.push_back(wine); }
    void remove(std::string wineName) { wines.erase(std::remove_if(wines.begin(), wines.end(), [&wineName](const Wine & w) { return w.name == wineName; }), wines.end()); }

    bool findAndPrint(std::string& wineName, std::ostream& os) {
        bool result = false;
        std::vector<Wine>::iterator found = std::find_if(wines.begin(), wines.end(), [&wineName](const Wine & w) { return w.name == wineName; });
        if (found != wines.end()) {
            os << "\nWine found:\n" << *found;
            result = true;
        }
        else
            os << "\nNo wine with this name found\n";
        return result;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Wines& w) {
        w.wines.clear();
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Wine>(is), std::istream_iterator<Wine>(), std::back_inserter(w.wines));
        return is;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Wines& w) {
        std::copy(w.wines.begin(), w.wines.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Wine>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    // One wine
    Wine wine;
    // A lsit with wines
    Wines wines;

    // Add some data
    std::cout << "\nEnter wine data. Name, Year, Place, Price, Type:\n";
    std::cin >> wine;
    wines.add(wine);

    std::cout << "\n\nEnter another wine data. Name, Year, Place, Price, Type:\n";
    std::cin >> wine;
    wines.add(wine);

    {
        // Store all wines on disk
        std::cout << "\nSaving on disk\n\n";
        std::ofstream database("c:\\temp\\winelist.txt");
        // Stores all wines in file
        if (database) database << wines;
    }
    {
        // Read back all wines from disk
        std::cout << "\nReading from disk\n\n";
        std::ifstream database("c:\\temp\\winelist.txt");
        // Reads the complete list from file
        if (database) database >> wines ;
    }

    // Search for a wine, if found, then remove it
    std::cout << "\n\nWine List:" << wines << "\n\n\nSearch for a wine. Enter a wine name:\n" << wines;
    std::string wineToSearch;
    std::cin >> wineToSearch;

    if (wines.findAndPrint(wineToSearch, std::cout)) {
        wines.remove(wineToSearch);
        std::cout << "\nRemoving wine from list: New List\n\n" << wines << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are of course tons of other possibilities. But you should get the idea.

Comment: Hm... 'correct direction' is very relative. You use uniform initialisation, although propagated by standard committee, there are others that consider UI flawed and using it the 'wrong direction'. Double for prices is questionable as well, as even 0.2, for instance, cannot be represented exactly. Others might consider the 'correct' way using integrals and fixed-comma arithmetic (e. g. calculate all prices in full cents – or tenth of, ...). `findAndPrint`? You are merging two actions into one function, better just find, printing itself can then be done via Wine's `operator<<`...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Thank you for your valuable comments. Appreciated. With direction, as I have written, I meant "Object Oriented Approach". Then I put some example code.based on OPs question. I agree and I would never use double and other things. As said, this is an example only. There are of course tons of other possibilities. But maybe people get the idea.